# OLYMPUS AIRのカメラプロパティに値が設定ができない

Tags: olympus-camerakit

Android: getVersion() = 1.1.0
Android: getBuildNumber() = 20150602

タブレット（Android)で、カメラの設定をしているのですが、
設定できません。設定しても読み出してみると元のままです。
使用している関数は

１．設定 setCameraPropertyValue
２．読込 getCameraPropertyValue

パラメータは　例えば　名称が "WB",設定値が `<WB/WB_LAMP>` などです。

なにか、プロテクト等がかかっているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく撮影モード（TAKEMODE）がiAutoのままだからではないかと思われます。

例えばPモードに変更したあと、WBなどを設定変更しますと正しく反映されると思います。

```
//撮影モードをPモードに変更
camera.setCameraPropertyValue("TAKEMODE","<TAKEMODE/P>");
//WBを晴天に変更
camera.setCameraPropertyValue("WB","<WB/MWB_FINE>");
```

[Olympus Camera Kit カメラプロパティリスト](https://opc.olympus-imaging.com/sdkdocs/data/PropertyList/property_list.html)の**対応する撮影モード**箇所に各プロパティが設定できる撮影モードが記述がありますので参考にしていただければと思います。
また、SDK添付のImageCaptureSampleのサンプルコードも参考になると思います。

Comment: ご指導ありがとうございます。
TAKEMODE/Pもできなかったのですが、これはRUMMODEを設定していなかったためでした。TAKEMODE/Pはできるようになりました。
ただ、WB/AUTOを LAMPやCUSTOM1に変更してみるのですが、読み出すと
元(AUTO)に戻ってしまいます。

Comment: SHUTTERの設定で失敗してました。ログにでてました。
WBの設定の前に　SHUTTERの設定で失敗していたため、WBにたどりつけていませんでした。
もうすこし、いろいろとトライしてみます。

Comment: SHUTTERを設定するには、TAKEMODE/SかMにしないとできないです。
プロパティリストの対応する撮影モードにSHUTTERを見るとSかMのみOKとなっていると思います。
その点を確認しないと同じことを繰り返しますよ。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。
設定を一気にしていましたが、個別に対応することにします。

Comment: こんな風にすると一括設定できると思います。
`Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("TAKEMODE", "<TAKEMODE/S>");
values.put("SHUTTER", "<SHUTTER/100>");
values.put("WB", "<WB/MWB_FINE>");
values.put("FACE_SCAN", "<FACE_SCAN/FACE_SCAN_OFF>");
camera.setCameraPropertyValues(values);
`